# Sorting with enhanced grid in dojo with structure attribute

Tags: sorting, dojo

We are trying to use the sorting functionality with dojo enhancedgrid. We have used a get method in the structure which creates another grid inside the row cell. Without the get method the sorting is working as expected. If we add the sorting functionality it is not showing any data.

Here is the sample code :-

```
var structure = {
                        onBeforeRow: onBeforeRow,
                        cells: [
                                [
                                        { name: 'Whatever', width: 4.5, get: getCheck, formatter: formatCheck, styles: 'text-align: center;' },
                                        {name: 'Column 0', get: get},
                                        {name: 'Column 1', get: get},
                                        {name: 'Column 2', get: get},
                                        {name: 'Column 3', get: get},
                                        {name: 'Column 4', get: get}
                                ],
                                [ { name: 'Detail', colSpan: 6, get: getDetail, formatter: formatDetail } ]
                        ]
                };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to null value in some of the cell. Due to which the sorting was failing from dojo.